# Bind for text of column stops working Bind stops working after hiding/showing this column and change its order

Tags: extjs, extjs6

There is something strange with bind column 'text' property.
I have gridcolumn with bind to 'text' property, like follows:

```
xtype: 'gridcolumn',
bind: {
    text: 'someTextFormula'
}
```

I hide and show this column.
Then I reorder columns using drag&drop.

Result: column text won't change, if formula changes.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uu5)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in a later release. The problem is inside `Ext.Component`, in the `onRemoved` method. If you remove the call to `removeBindings` it should fix the problem.